# how jquery access dynamic css :before and apply filter:brightness

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with jQuery and CSS.

Here is the code:

```
$("#test").append($("<div>",{
               style:"width:48%; margin-left:1%; margin-right:1%; margin-bottom:10px; float:left; background-image:url(http://test.png); filter:brightness(0.4); -webkit-filter:brightness(0.4);"
        }));
```

"#test" is parent div tag. and i want to append child div tag with that style like ":before" in css.

But I can't find any way to make dynamically ":before" code in jQuery. How can i fix this problem?

Can I make :before code and append this code to "#test"? Exactly, I have to make :before in jquery dynamically. :before does not exist in css .

This is the problem.

[image]

[image]

and this is that i want.

this div tag was made by jquery.

Comment: Since `::before` and `::after` are not really DOM elements, you can't add them via DOM manipulation.

Comment: why do you need a pseudo-element here? note that pseudo-element is just convenient for pure CSS, if using script, you can add various kinds of elements.

Comment: i know that. but is there any way to apply like :before in jquery??

Comment: *"to apply like :before in jquery"* Whats is that supposed to mean? If you are asking whether it's possible to insert an element before an other element, then yes, that's possible.

Comment: oh King King recently you teach me how filter:brightness apply. the answer was :before. but now i have to apply that in jqeury or javascript.

Comment: Are you after `$(selector).prepend()`?

Comment: what's the exact style you want to apply to the `:before`?

Comment: i want to apply background-image with filter:brigtness(0.4). and div will be made by dynamically in jqeury. and all child tag over parent have to be normal.

Comment: If you want to do what I think you want to do then no, it's not possible. It would be helpful if you'd provide a proper example and a better description of the problem though.

Comment: If you just want to set CSS properties on an element, then you can do that with `.css`: https://api.jquery.com/css/#css2. Otherwise I'm really clueless of what you are trying to do.

Comment: ok guys. i will update the question.

Comment: The edit doesn't help much. From the images I'd say you just have to set the text color to white. I'd suggest you take a step back and take your time to formulate a cohesive and complete question. But again if you want to insert a `::before` pseudo-element dynamically, the answer is that this is not possible.

Comment: what i want is that a div made by dynamically with jquery or javascript can be applied filter:brightness that is css code. and problem is that if i apply filter:brightness in jquery, then all child tag color in applied div also changed. one day ago, the solution of this was using :before in <style>. but that was not dynamic div. now i created div with jquery and i have to apply filter:brightness with child div color not changed.

Comment: Why don't you define your `::before` in CSS, for example `.myDiv:before { /* some CSS here */ }` and then add or remove the `myDiv` class as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can change the style of a pseudo-element is via the `CSSRule` (pure JS). However it requires you to define your selector (in CSS code) ***consistently*** (so that we can search for the rule successfully). After finding the rule, we can change the style easily. Your can also insert new rules to style your elements another way. After understanding your actual requirement, I updated the demo code here:

**HTML**:

```
<div>Pane 1</div>
<div>Pane 2</div>
<div>Pane 3</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  color:white;
}
div:before {
  content:'';   
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:-1;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

**JS**:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
//here is the main function to apply style 
//on the ::before of an element (passed in as elem)
function applyBeforeElementStyleOn(elem, styleProp, styleVal){
    //create new unique attribute for later selecting
    if(!elem.beforeElementStyle) {
      var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
      var currentTime = new Date();
      var guid = (currentTime + "" + 
                  currentTime.getMilliseconds()).replace(/[ :+()]/g,'') +
                 parseInt(Math.random()*1000);
      var ruleText = elem.tagName + "[" + guid + "]:before {}";
      sheet.insertRule(ruleText, 0);
      elem.beforeElementStyle = (sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules)[0].style;
      elem.setAttribute(guid.toLowerCase(),"");
    }    
    elem.beforeElementStyle[styleProp] = styleVal;
}
//test data
var data = [
  {bg: "url(http://placekitten.com/300/300)", brightness: 0.2},
  {bg: "url(http://placekitten.com/100/100)", brightness: 0.9},
  {bg: "url(http://placekitten.com/400/400)", brightness: 0.6},
];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
  applyBeforeElementStyleOn(divs[i], "background-image", data[i].bg);
  applyBeforeElementStyleOn(divs[i], "webkitFilter", 
                            "brightness(" + data[i].brightness + ")");
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LPJDC/1)

Comment: the reason i have to this is that some div has different background-image. could you apply some div with different image not one div? for example, each 5 div made by jquery or javascript has different background-image with dark brightness.

Comment: @MoonTaejin of course, all you need to do is set the style via `beforeElementStyle` such as `beforeElementStyle.backgroundImage = "url(http://placekitten.com/300/300)";` (however the `content` property seems not to be easily modified that way, we have to replace the cssText instead). Also the image should be cached to be displayed immediately.

Comment: what i understand is just one div image change. can i apply different image in each div? i think if i change beforeElementStyle.backgroundImage = "url(http://placekitten.com/300/300)"; then all div will be chaned as this image.

Comment: @MoonTaejin I misunderstood your requirement at first. Looks like we need more tweak to make it work that way. Please see my updated answer, it should work as what you want. Also you should consider using a normal element to render the background, that way you can modify its style easily, as I said pseudo-elements are just convenient for pure CSS.